# Handshake Problem Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I want to understand the idea behind why roommate pairs must sum to the same value. Here's a problem for context:

You and a roommate are hosting a party. You invite 10 other pairs of roommates. During the party you poll everyone at the party (excluding yourself) and ask how many hands each person shook.
Everyone at the party tells you a different number, and it is known that no two roommates shook hands. Based on this information, how many hands did you roommate shake?

Why is it that every set of roommates sum to 20 handshakes? Of course given this fact, it is trivial to see your roommate shook 10, but I don't understand the logic behind any two roommates summing to 20 handshakes. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am as puzzled as you are. Are you sure you have stated the full problem correctly? Please [edit] the question to quote it exactly.

Comment: Is there a specific solution you're reading to this problem, which begins by claiming that any two roommates sum to 20 handshakes without proof? This is a classic problem, but with the solution I know, it is only after you have determined everything else that you can go back and figure out who the roommates are.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I believe I have stated the problem in completion. Based on the fact everyone shook a different number of hands and no roommates shook hands, it apparently follows that any two roommates must have shook a combined 20 hands.

Comment: @EthanBolker this is in completion the problem I saw.

Comment: There are $21$ people other that yourself and nobody could shake more than $20$ hands (nor fewer than $0$) so you must have heard $0$ through $20$.  The $20$ person must be married to the $0$ person so, if you delete that couple from the count (and subtract all their handshakes) everybody else goes down by $1$...leaving you with the same problem and fewer couples, so induction applies.

Comment: @lulu why must the 20 person be married to the 0 person. That is exactly my question. Why couldn't they have both shaken hands.

Comment: Just think about it.  The $20-$person shook hands with *everybody* (other than their roommate).   That means that everybody, other than the roommate, shook hands with at least one person.

Comment: @lulu thanks! that's clever